# Windows 7: poor GUI response in my program while downloading data; is there some way to improve this?

Tags: windows-7, tcp, thread-priority

I've written a program that (among other things) downloads multiple large files from a server on the LAN, using TCP.  This program runs fine under Linux, MacOS/X, and generally under Windows as well (it uses Qt for the GUI and straight sockets calls for networking), but on certain Windows machines the download appears to be too much for the machine to handle, and I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas as to why that is and what can be done about it.

When downloading files, my program spawns a separate I/O thread that basically just sits in a loop, downloading data over TCP and writing it to a file, writing 128KB per call to QFile:write().  Each file is typically several hundred megabytes long, and a typical download session writes out several dozen of these files.  Note that the I/O thread runs independently of the GUI thread, so I wouldn't expect it to affect GUI's performance much if at all -- especially not when running on a multicore PC.

The PC in question is a Core-2Duo Quad Q6600 running at 2.40GHz, with 4GB of RAM.  It's running Windows 7 Ultimate SP1, 32-bit.  It is receiving data over a Gigabit Ethernet connection and writing it to files on the NTFS-formatted boot partition of the 232GB internal Hitachi ATA drive.

The symptom is that sometimes during a download (seemingly at random) the program's GUI will become non-responsive for 10 to 30 seconds at a time, and often the title bar of the window will have "(not responding)" appended to it.  The symptom will then clear up again and the download will proceed normally again.  Another symptom is that the desktop is extremely sluggish during the download... for example, if I click on the "Start" button, the Start menu will take ~30 seconds to populate, instead of being populated near-instantaneously as I would expect.

Note that Task Manager shows plenty of free memory, but it does show short spikes of CPU usage to 100% one one of the 4 cores, at the same time the problems are seen.

The data is arriving over Gigabit Ethernet, and if I have my program just receive the data and throw it away (without writing it to the hard drive), the machine can maintain a constant download rate of about 96MB/sec without breaking a sweat.  If I write the received data to a file, however, the download rate decreases to about 37MB/sec, and the symptoms described above start to appear.

The interesting thing is that just for curiosity's sake I added this call to my I/O thread's entry function, just before the beginning of its event loop:

```
SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL);
```

When I did that, the "(not responding)" symptoms cleared, but then download speed was reduced to only ~25MB/sec.

So my questions are:

- Does anyone know what might be causing the sporadic hangups of the GUI when the hard drive is under a heavy write-load?
- Why does lowering the I/O thread's priority cause the download rate to drop so much, given that there are three idle cores on the machine?  I would think that even a lower-priority thread would have plenty of CPU available in this situation.
- Is there any way to get a maximum download rate without causing Windows' desktop responsiveness and/or my app's GUI responsiveness to suffer problems?

Comment: Let me say something about the symptom during download that you describe. Exact same thing happens in my windows 7 ultimate during work hours at random like you say and I'm not running any heavy thread or process. It happens for any of the programs that I use for work, Access, Outlook, Word, Visual Studio, etc., specially when swithching programs with alt-tab, and randomly two or three time a day. I'm thinking it is Windows 7 itself but don't know what exactly.

Comment: Check this link out, it may be helpful in identifying what is causing your issue. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2265716/ I'm not suggesting you install the hotfix but take necessary precautions if you need to install any hotfix.

Comment: Jeremy, after adding my comment of Oct 21 at 23:36, I Googled this Windows 7 issue and followed a suggestion to stop and set to manual the 'Desktop Window Manager Session Manager' to solve the problem. After stopping the service on my work PC on Oct 24, I have no longer experienced that symptom; response and interaction with applications and GUI actually became a lot lighter and faster. The only "drawback" was the dissapearance of some Windows 7 GUI look & feel which I don't care.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code is hard to answer but this seems to be something related to processors and the fact that your download thread is not leaving any space for other threads to performs other operations.

It seems it never waits and that the driver of the network card is not well written.
Are you sure your thread is entering in an idle state when there is no data incoming?
In OS with a single processor a for (;;) {} will consume 100% cpu and if it talks continuously with the kernel it may stops other processes or other threads for doing that, especially if there is a bug or a very bad behaviour in some network card driver in your case.

Probably putting the thread priority below normal you are asking the OS to use your thread less often, this gives by a magical combination of things that allow things to not hang too much.
Check the code, maybe you are forgetting something?

Check if adding a sleep(0) to force the OS to yield to another thread sometime will make things better, but this is a temporary fix, you should find why your thread is consuming 100% cpu, if it is.

Comment: My thread doesn't consume 100% of the CPU, it blocks inside select() until more data is ready from the TCP socket.  (Of course given that the server can send data at 96MB/sec or more, select() does get unblocked a lot... but I'm quite confident that the code isn't busy-looping, at least not in userspace).  Also note that the computer in question has 4 cores, 3 of which remain idle at all times and the forth only spikes to 100% briefly.

Comment: Maybe we should look for other things like... what is the network adapter? what driver is it using? the last patches from windows update are installed? maybe the problem is not in your code!

Comment: Also, if the problem really was a networking problem I would expect the problem to remain present after I modified my program not to write the data to the disk... but if I do that, my program can download much faster (~96MB/sec) without any responsiveness issues.  It's only when writing to disk is enabled that I see trouble.  :^/

Comment: Mhhh maybe is something about pci express bus... both disk and network adapter nowadeys uses pci express.. May be is smething on the north bridge?